# In R, how create new dataframe with number of occurrences of each strings on other dataframe, like a product list and products in basket sold

Tags: r

Dataframe with each basket sold:

```
sells <- data.frame(buyers = c('buyer001', 'buyer002', 'buyer002'),
                      cart = c('apple > orange > grape > grape', 
                               'orange > orange', 'apple > grape'))
```

Dataframe with store stock

```
fruits <- data.frame(fruits = c('apple', 'orange', 'grape'))
```

Dataframe result

```
result <- data.frame(buyers = c('apple', 'orange', 'grape'),
                      cart = c(2, 3, 3))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
stack(table(unlist(strsplit(sells$cart, "\\W+"))))
  values    ind
1      2  apple
2      3  grape
3      3 orange
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the tidyverse (please see that the "fruits" object is not used)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sells %>%
    separate_rows(cart, sep = "\\s*>\\s*") %>%
    group_by(cart) %>%
    summarise(values = n())

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  cart   values
  <chr>   <int>
1 apple       2
2 grape       3
3 orange      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a `data.table` version.

```
library(data.table)
result = data.table(buyers = unlist(strsplit(sells$cart, "\\W+")))
result[, .(cart = .N), by=buyers]

   buyers cart
1:  apple    2
2: orange    3
3:  grape    3
```